# Difficulties of scraping using requests/pandas/beautiful soup caused by script

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the data from a flightradar website and want to save it as a `.csv` file.

Other websites have tables which makes it easy via `panda.read_html(url)` to read them.

On https://www.flightradar24.com/data/statistics, I'm having difficulties (probably because they don't want people to scrape their website).

The first difficulty I had was a 403 Forbidden which I solved by using a header

```
url = "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/statistics"

header = { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
```

Next problem I'm having is that in the source code the data is very hard to use since everything is only linked with non-useful numbers `[1633132800000,196045]` which are probably from the graph.

Because of that, I would like to use the table which can be shown over the hamburger button, or even better, download the csv-file over the hamburger button. This leads me to the next problem, the data table isn't in the downloaded source code and trying to find a download link for the csv-file leads me to a `blob:url` where I could only find even more complex solutions like cross-scripting.

So my question is if there is a better for this problem? They probably did a good job, because I'm having a hard time to find a solution which works well for me.

Comment: *scrape the data*, What data are you trying to scrape? Also, can you provide some boilerplate code?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `selenium` to download the `csv file` and then continue your data analysis. Since they also offer an `API service` I think, it's a bit more difficult to scrape data from there.

I'm pretty sure, as they use a diagram to visualize the data, you'd need to get the `csv` to use their data.

They use `javascript` so it won't be super easy to download these files with a bot. Refer this: [How to download a file using Selenium's WebDriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver)